# CefInitialize won't work from a mfc dll

Tags: mfc, chromium-embedded

I want to use Chromium Embeded Framework in an mfc dll. Therefore I created a mfc test exe and tested a minimalistic implementation of cef (which worked). My next step was to do exactly the same thing with a test mfc dll. The code is almost the same but the cef browser window won't come up.

The application hangs in CefInitialize() and won't return. After debugging, I found that it gets stuck in a WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObject windows api.

```
BOOL CMyBrowserDllApp::InitInstance()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    CefMainArgs main_args(hInstance);

    CefSettings settings;
    settings.no_sandbox = true;
    settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = true;

    // Execute the secondary process, if any.
    int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, cefApplication.get(), NULL);
    if (exit_code >= 0)
        return exit_code;

    if(!CefInitialize(main_args, settings, cefApplication.get(), NULL))
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("Error: CefInitialize failed");
    }else
        OutputDebugStringA("Info: CefInitialize succeeded");

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Same implementation works if used in a mfc exe directly.

Comment: Perhaps it is a matter of linking MFC statically or dynamically

Comment: Both projects are statically linked to the mfc dlls.

Comment: I ran into this same issue but I discovered you got help on the CEF forum. [Here's a link to the answer](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12065&sid=ac9bb443238c0cd5f5b994131734a0fa&start=10#p22628) for anyone else stuck in the same predicament:

Answer (score -1):

`GetModuleHandle` returns the base for the exe not the dll. You might want to stash the dll base from:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, void *reserved)
```